# Creating custom legends in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a data set that I add multiple layers to the original data and colors for this information. I want to highlight specific plots on the graph and add those to a legend. From what I have found I can't create fully custom legends on ggplot like I can on the base plot function of R. Here is a sample of what I am trying to:

```
     mm1 <- c(40,35,55,35,46,68)
     mm2 <- c(47568,45635,60453,35424,35215,55043)
     mm3 <- data.frame(cbind(mm1,mm2))
     colnames(mm3) = c('ConL','traderL')

     ggplot(mm3,aes(traderL,ConL))+
       geom_jitter()+
       geom_point(aes(x=traderL[1],y=ConL[1]),
                  size = 3,
                  color = 'blue')+
       geom_point(aes(x=traderL[2],y=ConL[2]),
                  size = 3,
                  color = 'red')+
       geom_point(aes(x=traderL[3],y=ConL[3]),
                  size = 3,
                  color = 'red')+
       geom_point(aes(x=traderL[4],y=ConL[4]),
                  size = 3,
                  color='red')
```

the first geom_point highlights the most recent week of data (this data is released weekly) and I want to add that to a legend, same with the remaining geom_points.

I have tried looking online and haven't found any solutions

Comment: If you want a legend, you need to have something mapped in the `aes()`. rather than usign `color="red"` outside the `aes()`, use `color="recent"` or something like that inside the `aes()` and then use `scale_color_manual()` to set what color you want to use for "recent" in the plot. Do the same for the other categories as well.